# "Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled", but I have JavaScript enabled by default

Tags: bug, status-norepro, javascript

Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow prompts me that "Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled". But I reconfirmed that I have my JavaScript enabled by default. I am using Firefox 3.6.

Comment: Not confirmed on Firefox 3.6 on Windows. Are you sure you have no local setting enabled to turn JS off?

Comment: no but everything is working fine apart from the prompt

Comment: I refreshed page again, it went away.

Comment: Related: *[Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208)* Contains input for JavaScript whitelisting (what Internet domains are actually used, etc.), cookies, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be caused by Google's CDN being blocked, and hence [its jQuery](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js) not being available:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
```

For some time, [the JavaScript](http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js) also outputted “Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled” when jQuery was not loaded. In [March 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81546/stackoverflow-com-javascript-disabled-banner/81561#81561) it became more specific:

```js
// display a warning (like the noscript warning) even if JS is enabled, but
// jQuery isn't there (google CDN blocked etc.)
// -- no jQuery is as good as no JavaScript at all for our purposes
var checkForJQuery = function (siteName) {
  if (!window.jQuery) {
     ...
     warning.innerHTML = siteName + " works best with jQuery enabled";
```

And [somewhere in April 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-message) this changed to:

```
if(!window.jQuery)
  ...
  c.innerHTML = a +
  " requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.";
```

Note that the above will not work if Stack Exchange's own `sstatic.net` CDN is blocked, as then the above JavaScript is not even loaded. Except on Meta, where the static resources are not loaded from that domain. So, here on Meta one might get the warning, while on the other sites things fail silently if `sstatic.net` is blocked.

So, for future searches:

> Stack Overflow works best with jQuery enabled
>   Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.

Comment: And, [some say](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81546/stackoverflow-com-javascript-disabled-banner/82247#82247) that Internet Explorer's "InPrivate Filtering" ([others](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80044/cant-ask-a-question-when-ie-tracking-protection-is-enabled/80049#80049) blame "Tracking Protection"; might be the same thing) might block Google's CDN, when it notices that its domain is used by many web-pages, and hence figures it must be an ad.

Comment: And for [some](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84979/stackoverflow-bug-in-firefox-4-0-javascript-not-working-even-if-its-enabled) an old version of AdBlock blocked the loading of jQuery.

Comment: My Firewall was blocking the js file.That was the problem...Thanks a lot ya...

Comment: @biju: It'd be great if you posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see this in Firefox 3.6 (latest) on stackoverflow.com either.

I suspect you either have non-default settings, or a rogue plugin. Try starting Firefox in safe mode and see if it persists.

Comment: yes.I better check for some plugins or addons

Comment: oops i had webdeveloper toolbar installed and eventhough javascript was enabled,i have disable java checked.I think thats the problem.let me see if it occurs again

Comment: It still remains even after i remove the disable java check.Noe i will try unchecking strict warnings

Answer (score 1):

In my Firewall i had a rule to block the extension .js.I removed .js from the banned extensions list and added

> ajax.googleapis.com

to the exceptions list in blocked sites.Now everything is working fine.Thanks everyone especially Arjan.

Comment: Others might also need `sstatic.net` (Stack Exchange's static resources) to be added to such list, to allow for fetching [the site's own JavaScript](http://sstatic.net/js/master.min.js). But, when that is blocked, no "works best with" message would be shown either as it's that script that shows the very message.

Comment: already got the unblocked

Comment: I knew you did, as you did get that message :-) (As an aside: see [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work))

Comment: @Arjan :) ya got it...;)