# Stack Overflow bug in Firefox 4.0 - JavaScript not working even if it's enabled

Tags: support, firefox

I'm getting a red bar on top of each page which says "Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled". My JavaScript is enabled. Otherwise everything is working well.

EDIT: nope, I am not using [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) and am also not seeing jQuery effects. It's not blocked. Everything worked well in Firefox 3.6 before I updated.

EDIT 2: [AdBlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus) was the culprit. Updating AdBlock fixes it.

EDIT 3: Nope, not Adblock. Not any of the extensions (uninstalled everything, not just disabled). It's an intermittent problem. Sometimes it will show the red bar, but refreshing the page will fix it. Other times refreshing it won't fix it at all. Usually it works. Looks like a bug.

Comment: have you installed noscript?

Comment: Are you seeing the effects that rely on jQuery? Like when hovering a tag, or when hovering your own username? See also [Employer blocks jQuery from Google, DOH!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10071/employer-blocks-jquery-from-google-doh)

Comment: nope, didn't install noscript. when the bug acts up, i can't see any jquery effects.

Comment: Try clearing the cache of Firefox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using Firefox 4.0 and I get no such warning; JavaScript works fine on Stack Overflow. You are likely using any addons that are disabling JavaScript, such as NoScript. Try disabling them, or creating an exception for Stack Overflow. See also this question: [“Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled”, but I have JavaScript enabled by default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72020/stack-overflow-works-best-with-javascript-enabled-but-i-have-javascript-enable)

Comment: Updated AdBlock Plus to 1.3.5 and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Actually, no. updating adblock doesn't fix the problem. It is intermittent - sometimes it will show the red bar, but refreshing the page will fix it. Other times refreshing it won't fix it at all. Usually it works. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 2):

[Up to the end of March](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81546/stackoverflow-com-javascript-disabled-banner/81561#81561), this text *could* have been caused by Google's CDN being blocked. Not so much anymore; the text is really coming from the following HTML:

```
<noscript>
  <div id="noscript-warning">
    Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled 
    [...]
  </div>
</noscript>
```

I really think your browser or add-ons are to blame.

Comment: *Unless* you're seeing a totally different message: *Stack Overflow works best with jQuery enabled*.

Comment: This was what I first thought too, but now I've uninstalled (not just disabled) all my add-ons, and it still happens intermittently. Funny thing is, refreshing a page will sometimes fix the problem.

Comment: There is no way that Stack Exchange can make your browser interpret [the HTML `<noscript>`](http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/noscript/) erroneously, @maranas. When it happens again, maybe a view source followed by a search for that `<noscript>` can reveal something changed the HTML source? I assume you would have noticed a bad internet connection. (And, again, just to be sure, you're REALLY not seeing a slightly different message, right?)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely extension related.  I'm using Firefox 4, with minimal extensions (web developer + firebug), and have experienced no problems.  try disabling all extensions, and then re-enabling them one by one until you find the extension (or combination thereof) that generates the problem.  If you still get the problem with absolutely no extensions installed, it is indeed an odd problem.